# Facing error while logging Entrust Authority Security manager

Tags: security

I am facing below error while logging into Entrust Authority Security manager server version 7.1.

**"Unable to retrieve valid certification revocation list"**

This installation was working properly before 1 year. Now when i tried to login we are getting the above error. Can anyone please help on this issue.

Thanks Santhosha K

Comment: @leppie If his cert expired he would get a different error.

Comment: I have changed the system date and tried again now  i am getting the error "The user's public or private key is invalid"

Answer (score 0):

This is becuase the [OCSP server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) that is being run by the Certificate Authority cannot be accessed.  It is very likely that their machine is down for maintenance,  but it could be down or inaccessible for other reasons.

Like with any utility,  call your CA and notify them of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you will check in the event-viewer the error code 2658 would be reported for such case. This is basically because the workstation clock has been advanced intentionally or Security Manager application is not aware of the time change. Please start Entrust/Master Control to acknowledge the time change or correct your clock.

Do following and the login to Security Manager would be successful

1. Start Entrust/Master Control to acknowledge the time change or correct your clock. During the login process, a message is displayed indicating that Entrust/Master Control Time is not the same as the machine time. The user is asked whether or not they want Entrust/Master Control to put these changes into effect.
2. Click OK.
3. Start the Entrust/Authority services in Entrust/Master Control.